# how to set the scroller to max in its initial value flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am building an chat app. I want whenever the chat class open it scrolled to max initially. 
i tried the below code but it's wrong

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController = ScrollController();
    scrollController.animateTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10), curve: Curves.easeOut);
  }
```

Comment: accepting a helpful answer on stackoverflow signifies to future readers that it is helpful, it is also a sign of appreciation for the time the person spent solving your problem. And it is a way to earn some reputation points.

Comment: definitely i provide the feedback after trying this

Answer (score 1):

I'm also building an app with chatting integrated, and I had the same problem. I fixed it by making it  `addPostFrameCallback` when building. This is called everytime the widget is rebuilt.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    scrollController.jumpTo(positionToScroll);
}

}
```

You can use `animateTo` instead of `jumpTo` and it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, any scrollable widget is not rendering in `initstate` yet.
You can try to change the scroll position after your scrollable widget is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addPostFrameCallback` from `SchedulerBinding` to force `ScrollController` to move only when the building process completes, guaranteeing it has an initial position to move from :

1. Import `Scheduler` :

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
   ```
2. Modify your `initState()` :

   ```
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     scrollController = ScrollController();
     SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => scrollController.animateTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10), curve: Curves.easeOut));
   }
   ```

Comment: this is giving me an error "ScrollController not attached to any scroll views."